# Pie, Shiny in R

Tags: r, shiny

I want to make the slider on the left change the number of classes shown in the pie. What line do I need to add/change to make it do that?
Here is my CSV file data:

[image]

Here is the code I wrote:

```
    library(shiny)
    library(readr)
    GiuseppeData <- read_csv("Classes_with_Giuseppe.csv")

#As I understand the line should be added/changed in this part
#Here I Define UI for application that draws a pie

    ui <- fluidPage(
        
# App title ----
    

    titlePanel("Hello Giuseppe!"),
        
# Sidebar layout with input and output definitions ----
    
    sidebarLayout(
            
# Sidebar panel for inputs ----
        
    sidebarPanel(
            
# Input: Slider for the number of bins ----
            
    sliderInput(inputId = "bins",
                        label = "Amount of Classes",
                        min = 1,
                        max = 18,
                        value = 7)
                        
            
        ),
            
# Main panel for displaying outputs ----
       
    mainPanel(
                
# Output: Histogram ----
            

    plotOutput(outputId = "distPie")
         )
        )
    )

# Define server logic required to draw a pie

    server <- function(input, output) {
    
    output$distPie <- renderPlot({
        
        x    <- GiuseppeData$length_of_classes
        bins <- seq(min(x), max(x), length.out = input$bins + 1)
        
        pie(x, breaks = bins, col = "76776", border = "pink",
             xlab = "Pie of Length of Each Class (in hours)",
             main = "Pie of Classes")
        
    })
    
    }

# Run the application 
   

     shinyApp(ui = ui, server = server)
```

Comment: So if I understand you correctly if input$bins is put to 10 you want a piechart with only class 1 until class 10? If so I would do: `x <- GiuseppeData[1:input$bins,"length_of_classes"]` and remove the bins part inside `renderPlot` and `pie`

Comment: @WietsedeVries hi, thank you for your comment! I tried to do that but when i run the program it gives me error: 'x' values must be positive.

Comment: # Define server logic required to draw a pie
server <- function(input, output) {
    
    output$distPie <- renderPlot({
        
        x <- GiuseppeData[1:input$bins,"length_of_classes"]
        
        
        pie(x, col = "76776", border = "pink",
             xlab = "Pie of Length of Each Class (in hours)",
             main = "Pie of Classes")
        
    })
    
}

# Run the application 
shinyApp(ui = ui, server = server)

Comment: Hmmm, are you using graphics::pie, or do you have another package running?

Comment: Actually, nevermind that. It's because of `readr` importing the table as spec_tbl_df. To simplify, use this instead: `x <- GiuseppeData[1:input$bins,]$length_of_classes`

Comment: I do have package graphics running, does the code work for you when you try to execute it?

Comment: now it works! Thank you a lot. Also, I noticed that divisions on the slider are shown at the end of it only, is there a way to correct it?

Comment: Please do not put answers in comments. @user778: if the problem is solved you can post the answer yourself and accept it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For sake of completeness.

Rewrite the `renderPlot` portion to this:

```
output$distPie <- renderPlot({
        
    x <- GiuseppeData[1:input$bins,]$length_of_classes
        
    pie(x, col = "76776", border = "pink",
         xlab = "Pie of Length of Each Class (in hours)",
         main = "Pie of Classes")
        
})
```

Frankly, I don't know what you were trying to achieve with `breaks = bins` as `breaks` is not a valid parameter for `pie`, but the idea of this code is that you select rows 1 until the number of rows specified by the `sliderInput` (`input$bins`). Then, you select the column `length_of_classes` using the `$` operator, which will automatically convert the single column to a numeric vector.

Small footnote: in regular `data.frames` you can also use  `GiuseppeData[1:input$bins,"length_of_classes"]` as regular data.frames will automatically convert single column tables to a vector. However, the `readr` package that you are using does not import files as `data.frame` but as a `spec_tbl_df`, therefore the `$` operator is required